# data.table bug: lapply on .SD reorder columns when using get(). Possible workaround?

Tags: r, data.table

I found a strange behavior of `data.table`. I would like to know if there is a way to avoid it, or a workaround.

In my data management, I use often `lapply` with `.SD`, to assign new values to columns. To assign properly several columns, the order of the output column of the `lapply` must be kept. 
I found a situation where it is not the case.

Here the normal behavior

```
library(data.table)
plouf <- data.table(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
cols <- c("y","x")
plouf[,.SD,.SDcols = cols ,by = z]
plouf[,lapply(.SD,function(x){x}),.SDcols = cols ,by = z]
plouf[,lapply(.SD[x == 1],function(x){x}),.SDcols = cols ,by = z]
```

All these lines give :

```
   z y x
1: 3 2 1
```

which I need for example to reassign to c("y","x"). But if I do:

```
plouf[,lapply(.SD[get("x") == 1],function(x){x}),.SDcols = c("y","x"),by = z]

   z x y
1: 3 1 2
```

Here the order of x and y changed without reason, when it should yield the same result as the last "working" example. If then assign the wrong values to `c("y","x")` if I assign the output of `lapply` to new vector of columns. It seems that the use of `get` in the `i` part of `.SD` triggers this bug.

Example of the effect of this on assignment:

```
plouf[, c(cols ) := lapply(.SD[get("x") == 1],function(x){x}),
      .SDcols = cols ,by = z][]
#    x y z
# 1: 2 1 3
```

Does anyone have a workaround ? The code I am using looks more like :

```
 plouf[, c(cols ) := lapply(.SD[get("x") >= 1 & get("x") <= 3],function(x){mean}),
          .SDcols = cols ,by = z]
```

the issue on github: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4089

Comment: One temporary solution could be: `.SD[["x"]] == 1` instead of `get("x") == 1`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more suitable at https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues

Comment: Instead of `get("x") == 1` you can use `eval(substitute(v == 1, list(v = as.symbol("x"))))`. That avoids the issue.

Comment: @sindri_baldur it works in this example, but in my case I use a more complex condition, like `get(x) >=1 & get(x) <=3 `

Comment: @zx8754 I will post there, but the idea of my post was to get a workaround

Comment: @denis `.SD[["x"]] %between% c(1, 3)`. Maybe update your post to make clear you are looking for workaround, and add link to your github issue report?

Comment: @Roland Yes, this does the trick, thanks for the possible solution (although a bit hard to read)

Comment: @denis No problem, community doesn't need to agree with my close vote. Just thought to bring this *"bug"* into attention of developers. Here on SO will get you a *workaround* not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subsetting `.SD`, you could do the subsetting in your lapply function. If the logical vector used for subsetting is passed as a third argument to lapply it isn't re-evaluated at each lapply pass.

Note: I changed the function to multiply by 10 since otherwise I couldn't tell if the code was doing anything at all

```
plouf[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x, i) 10*mean(x[i]), 
                         get("x") %between% c(1, 3)), 
      .SDcols = cols ,by = z][]

#     x  y z
# 1: 10 20 3
```

There are other workarounds that would allow you to subset .SD, but I think subsetting `.SD` by group is slower than subsetting each column individually.

```
set.seed(0)
df <- rep(1:50000, sample(500:1000, 50000, T)) %>% 
        data.table(a = runif(length(.))
                  ,b = .)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  subSD = df[, lapply(.SD[a < .2], sum), b]
  , in_func = df[, lapply(.SD, function(x, i) sum(x[i]), a < .2), b]
  , times = 10L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min         lq      mean     median        uq       max neval cld
#    subSD 19323.19 20398.3666 21289.345 20708.4346 22466.010 23738.467    10   b
#  in_func   972.64   987.7891  1016.252   995.4236  1038.069  1125.709    10  a
```

Edit: bigger benchmark

```
set.seed(0)
rm(df)
df <- rep(1:5e5, sample(50:100, 5e5, T)) %>% 
        data.table(a = runif(length(.))
                  ,b = .)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  subSD = df[, lapply(.SD[a < .2], sum), b]
  , in_func = df[, lapply(.SD, function(x, i) sum(x[i]), a < .2), b]
  , times = 2L)

# Unit: seconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
#    subSD 207.111290 207.111290 214.147649 214.147649 221.18401 221.18401     2   b
#  in_func   3.560467   3.560467   3.651359   3.651359   3.74225   3.74225     2  a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know that I could write it this way, I like it a lot

Answer (score 1):

In the bug report of github, @jangoreki suggested:

---

> As a workaround you can use now substitute rather than get

```
var = "x"
expr = substitute(
  plouf[, c(cols) := lapply(.SD[.var == 1],function(x){x}), .SDcols = cols, by = z][],
  list(.var=as.name(var))
)
print(expr)
#plouf[, `:=`(c(cols), lapply(.SD[x == 1], function(x) {
#    x
#})), .SDcols = cols, by = z][]
eval(expr)
#   x y z
#1: 2 1 3
```

> Personally I would use it regularly, not as a workaround, I find R metaprogramming features superior.
>   Also be aware that some day instead of `get(var)` we should be able to use `..var`, see (#2816, #3199)
>   R metaprogramming always worked and, I assume, will always work, thanks to the conservative backward compatible R code development.